# Finding an analytic function

Tags: power-series, analyticity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iul9L.png)

I cannot find any such function. Also, why would a function that is analytic at 0 following these criteria not be analytic on (-2,0). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please click the link to view the question

Comment: Hint: $1/(z+1)$.

Comment: 1 - 1/(n+1) equals n/(n+1), but how do I get a function f for which f(1/n) is equal to that?

Comment: Some effort is needed. But I continue to like my hint.

Comment: Hint: if you know $f(1/n)$ in terms of $n$, what is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see how that would work. Thank you. So the function could not be analytic at -1?

Comment: That particular function can't, but it could be another one.

Comment: Then how could I prove that any such function could not be analytic on that interval?

Comment: Next step: $(1+\frac1n)f(\frac1n)=1$. Now it really depends on what you know about analytic functions, but this is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

let $z={1 \over n}$, then $f(z) = {{1 \over z} \over {1 \over z}+1} = {1 \over 1+z}$.

Does this suggest anything?

Note that if $f,g$ are analytic on some domain $D$ and agree on a collection of points which have a limit point in $D$ then $f=g$ on $D$.

Where is the pole of this function? How does this limit analyticity?

Note that the question is a little ambiguous; the resulting function will 
certainly be analytic on $(-1,0)$.

Comment: The end of the first line should read z/(1+z). Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Roberto: Where did you get ${z \over 1+z}$ from?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong?

Comment: @Roberto: You do realise that the first line is not ${z \over 1+z}$, right?

Comment: I guess it is more passive aggressiveness.